# Have a problem when call api with Content-Type: application/json (lumen/react fetch)

Tags: php, reactjs, http, lumen

I have trying to call api(lumen) with Content-Type: application/json but it has error like this

> Access to fetch at 'https://api.xxx.com/api/v1/test' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

My fetch code is.

```
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    fetch('https://api.xxx.com/api/v1/test', requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
```

But when i remove header like this

```
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    fetch('https://api.xxx.com/api/v1/test', requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
```

It work fine.

My back-end API function is

```
    public function test(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json(["data" => "ok"], 200);
    }
```

I have using fruitcake/laravel-cors,
here is my config

```
    'paths' => ['api/*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried to use `body: data` when you remove the headers?

Comment: When i remove header or use 'Content-Type: text/plain' it work properly, if i using 'Content-Type: application/json' it error about CORS.
The data in body is just
{
   "data": "test"
}

Comment: Have you tried that endpoint with another client? Postman, Axios, for example?

Comment: The Postman is not have a problem, but axios have.